# Gitlab DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG with multiple robot accounts from the same registry

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, harbor

I use Harbor as a private Registry for my Docker images, and I store my images in different projects (ex: myproject1, myproject2, etc).

Then I create one robot account in my project "myproject1" and one robot account in "myproject2"

Finally, I use the DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG variable in Gitlab to set up robot accounts, such as :

```
{
    "auths": {
        "myharborregistry/myproject1": {
            "auth": "base64.... token 1 created in myproject1"
        },
        {
        "myharborregistry/myproject2": {
            "auth": "base64.... token 2 created in myproject2"
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that with this configuration, Gitlab randomly takes one of the 2 authentications to pull the image in "myproject1"

As a result, my pipelines crash randomly (because Gitlab takes the robot account of "myproject2")

Do you have a solution to force the use of the right robot account depending on the project targeted?

Regards,

Jeremy

I tried with :

```
{
    "auths": {
        "myharborregistry/myproject1": {
            "auth": "base64.... token 1 created in myproject1"
        },
        {
        "myharborregistry/myproject2": {
            "auth": "base64.... token 2 created in myproject2"
        }
    }
}
```

And I got "Permission denied" randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Harbor supports [System wide robot accounts](https://container-registry.com/docs/administration-manual/system-robot-accounts/). (Since Version 2.4) This robot account can be used for multiple projects